# The 2.1, "similar" path is returning empty results

Tags: bug, api-v2.1

I've been a happy user of [the /2.1/similar Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/similar) for a while. But, at some point within the last 24 hours, or so, it started returning empty results (but otherwise reporting everything as good).

I am seeing the same behavior from [the doc examples](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/similar#order=desc&sort=activity&title=help%20with%20stuff&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

It does not matter which site I search or which search terms I use. And yes; I triple checked that I am not busting the rate limit or otherwise getting errors reported :-)

Comment: Seems to be working now.  If it happens again, try to capture (and post in the Question) the *exact* path+query+filter versus the *exact* JSON results.